# How to Listplot the values obtained by a For loop

Tags: plotting

I need to ListLinePlot the values generated by a For loop. For example consider the coding

```
For[t = 0, t <= 10, t += 1, der[x_] = t^2 + 125; Print[der[x]]]
```

The above code prints the ten values manipulated by the For loop but instead if i need to do ListLinePlot of the values how can i do it.. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use a `For`. You could try

```
der[t_] := t^2 + 125;
data = der[#] & /@ Range[0, 10];
ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "der(t)"}, BaseStyle -> 12, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another option is to have the `x,y` generated at same time

```
der[t_] := t^2 + 125;
data = {#, der[#]} & /@ Range[0, 10];
ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "der(t)"}, BaseStyle -> 12, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could also use `Table` command to generate the data.

Comment: Hai thanks for your reply. But i am in a situation to calculate the expression when 't' takes values from 0-10 in steps of 0.001.. and then do ListLinePlot of the obtained values. can you give me any suggestions for this issue

Comment: @vicky  you can just change the `Range` command to give it a specific increment. By default it is 1. Use the third argument. Like this `der[t_] := t^2 + 125;
data = {#, der[#]} & /@ Range[0, 10, 0.001];
ListLinePlot[data, AxesLabel -> {"t", "der(t)"}]`